# Delete Git log or commit id after merging a branch

Tags: git, github

I would like to delete Git logs after merging.
I have tried `git rebase -i` and `git reset --hard` but `bbb` branch commit logs doesn't change.
I have deleted `bbb` branch but 3 logs have not been deleted from the Sourcetree.
The `bbb` branch has 3 logs now,  so I would like to delete 2 commits from the log or delete `bbb` branch.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX3yh.png)

After deleting the `bbb` branch, Git condition is like this picture.
I still can see commit logs for the `bbb` branch.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKqSZ.png)

I have tried `git rebase -i xxx`, and replaced to `squash`. But I still can see commit logs like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLiWQ.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Comment: you want to `squash` the commits of the branch getting merged into your base branch. you should have a single commit where you can add a new message.

Comment: Your solution is to delete the commits (by squashing) **before the merge**. For that, see the link above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to do with the commits but to delete the `bbb` branch run `git push -d <remote_name> <branch_name>` to delete the remote branch and `git branch -d <branch_name>` to delete the local branch

Comment: Thank you for editing and answering my question. I have tried to delete the `bbb` branch. But also I would like to delete git commit logs. I still can see commit logs for the `bbb` branch.

Comment: I would suggest you revert back to the point that you wanted to delete the `bbb` branch using `git rebase -i HEAD~N`
The ~N means rebase the last N commits (N must be a number, for example HEAD~3). Then, you can delete the `bbb` branch.